# Firebase function logs show failure even function succeeds

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've got a firebase function that seems to work correctly, but the logs indicate failure.

I'm seeing log messages like `Function execution took xxx ms. Finished with status: response error`.

Here's a screenshot of the logs when the HTTP function is triggered.

[image: image of logs]

It's strange that the logging level is "Debug."  None of the `logger.error` statements in the code are triggered.

The code itself is not complicated but even when I simplify it down to this, I'm seeing the error message in the logs.

```
export const shirtOrders = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 300,
    memory: "512MB",
  })
  .https.onRequest(async (request: any, response: any) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
      logger.info("Hello");

      response.status(201).send(JSON.stringify({ result: "ok" }));
    });
  });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you tried catching any exceptions that may be thrown by your function? Maybe this way you'll get a proper error message which will make it better to troubleshoot.